# Unable to clone button with on click function with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, onclick

I have button to show phone number if clicked with this code:

```
var shortNumber = $("#phone_ch").text().substring(0,  $("#phone_ch").text().length - 12);
var onClickInfo = "_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'EVENT-CATEGORY', 'EVENT-ACTION', 'EVENT-LABEL', VALUE, NON-INTERACTION]);";
$("#phone_ch").hide().after('<div id="clickToShowPc" onClick="' + onClickInfo + '">' + shortNumber + 'X XXXXXXXX</div>');
$('section:has(div.price_c,div.contact_name_info,div#clickToShowPc)').addClass('xoom_c');
$("#clickToShowPc , #phone_cc").click(function() {
  $("#phone_ch").show();
  $("#phone_cc").hide();
  $("#clickToShowPc").hide();
});
```

And I try to clone it with this code:

```
$( ".phone_c" ).clone(true , true).attr('class', 'phone_c col-lg-6').appendTo( ".main-section" );
```

And this is the original button HTML:

```
<div class="phone_c col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
  <span id="phone_ch" style="display: none;">  012 73962304</span><div id="clickToShowPc" onclick="_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'EVENT-CATEGORY', 'EVENT-ACTION', 'EVENT-LABEL', VALUE, NON-INTERACTION]);">  01X XXXXXXXX</div>
  <div id="phone_cc">Show phone</div>
</div>
```

The button cloned but with showing the hidden elements and If I click it it will show the hidden element on the original one.

Can some one advise me with the correct code please?

I tried to search here and I found that I need to enable the

```
.clone(true , true)
```

in my code. And also I found something about duplicating ID's but it was not clear to me and I failed to solve my problem.

Thank you

Comment: post the html too, and Id must be unique, otherwise the first element with that element will be used, meaning that's the reason why the click on the cloned button shows hidden stuff on the original one

Comment: Thank you, I added the HTML code and is it poosibel to advise how to change the ID's for sub divs?

Comment: hello. you can use class instead of id, and select the parent object and then use .find or something like that to select the children  that you want to show on the click event.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you clone your div ".phone_c", you will have multiple elements with the same ID. So, when you use the DOM Selector "#phone_cc", it will select the first one because it's how it works. If you had :

```
<span class="phone_ch" style=...
```

So you could use the DOM Selector ".phone_cc" and all elements with that class will be selected.
Now, you want to show and hide only elements "near" the cloned clicked element. To do that, you will have to use classes instead of IDs.

```
<div class="phone_c col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
<span class="phone_ch" style="display: none;">  012 73962304</span>
<div class="clickToShowPc" onclick="_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'EVENT-CATEGORY', 'EVENT-ACTION', 'EVENT-LABEL', VALUE, NON-INTERACTION]);">  01X XXXXXXXX</div>
<div class="phone_cc">Show phone</div>
</div>
```

Then try to reach the parent element to reach the children :

```
    var shortNumber = $(".phone_ch").text().substring(0, $(".phone_ch").text().length - 12);
var onClickInfo = "_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'EVENT-CATEGORY', 'EVENT-ACTION', 'EVENT-LABEL', VALUE, NON-INTERACTION]);";

$(".phone_ch").hide().after('<div class="clickToShowPc" onClick="' + onClickInfo + '">' + shortNumber + 'X XXXXXXXX</div>');

$('section:has(div.price_c,div.contact_name_info,div.clickToShowPc)').addClass('xoom_c');

$(".clickToShowPc , .phone_cc").click(function() {
  var parent = $(this).parent();
  $(".phone_ch", parent).show();
  $(".phone_cc", parent).hide();
  $(".clickToShowPc", parent).hide();
});
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you very much it solve most of thee problem. but the  `<span class="phone_ch"> 012 233232323</span>` is not hiding and always show. Can you advise please?

Comment: Are you sure of that ? When I tested it, I could only see the "clickToShowPc" span, may you confound with the ".phone_ch" span no ?

Comment: I changed the span to be `<div class="phone_ch" style="display: none;">`, and also I changed the rest to be class not ID, and the HTML output look like this: `<div class="clickToShowPc" onclick="_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'EVENT-CATEGORY', 'EVENT-ACTION', 'EVENT-LABEL', VALUE, NON-INTERACTION]);">  012   73962304  01X XXXXXXXX</div>`, Please can you advise?

Comment: If there is one element only on the screen, the output will look OK, but when I clone it only `<span class="phone_ch"` is showing and not hiding. Sorry, the first code it was div by mistake not span

Comment: You can put in your style a display:none for the class ".phone_ch" or you can hide the element after your clone.
`var newelem = $( ".phone_c" ).clone(true , true)
  newelem.attr('class', 'phone_c col-lg-6').appendTo( ".main-section" );
  $(".phone_ch", newelem).hide();
`
But you should use a css code instead of that.

Comment: Yes, My code has a problem and as you said, its work just fine with your first code. Thank you for this. I accepted the answer